# Core Data or sqlite for fast search?

Tags: macos, sqlite, cocoa, core-data

This is a description of the application I want to build and I'm not sure whether to use Core Data or Sqlite (or something else?):

- Single user, desktop, not networked, only one frontend is accessing datastorage
- User occasionally enters some data, no bulk data importing or large data inserts
- Simple datamodel: entity with up to 20-30 attributes
- User searches in data (about 50k datasets max.)
- Search takes place mostly in attribute values, not looking for any keys here, but searching for text in values

Writing the data is nothing I see as critical, it happens not very often and with small amounts of data. The text search in the attributes has to be blazingly fast, a user would expect almost instant results. This is absolutely critical.

I would rather go with Core Data, but is this a scenario CD can handle?

Thanks

-Fish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data can handle this scenario. But because you're looking for blazingly fast full text search, you'll have to do some extra work. Session 211 of WWDC 2013 goes into depth about how to do this (slides 117-131). You'll probably want to have a separate Entity with text search tokens: all of the findable words in your dataset.

Although one of the FTS extensions is available in Apple's deployment of SQLite, it's not exposed in Core Data.